# Pandas loc and apply changes to dataframe problem .. getting error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe .. pseudo this is what I want to do.

If value in plcg column does not equal 1, then do an equation to other columns and add the result to a new column... Probably not explained very well .. Currently this is the code I have.

```
formula = (df['Margin']/5.5)+df['Time']
df.loc[df['Plcg'] != '1', "real_time"] = formula
```

How do I change this so it doesn't throw the index error?

Comment: `df['real_time']=np.where(df['Plcg'] != '1',formula,df['real_time'])` ? or if 1 is int remove the quotes , ideally your code should have worked better create a reproducible example

Comment: Numpy wins again, that worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user anky_91 for providing an alternative to get around the index issue.

```
df['real_time']=np.where(df['Plcg'] != '1',formula,df['real_time'])
```